# Twilio REST API Security Changes for June 2019 - PHP SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

We received notification from Twilio regarding Security changes.

We are using PHP SDK. Do we need to need take any action in this regard? If so, what should we do?

Comment: This really should be addressed to Twilio support. What security changes? What code? What actions have **they** suggested that you take?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to read this notice and follow the instructions:

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007724794-Notice-Twilio-REST-API-s-TLS-and-Cipher-Suite-Security-Changes-for-June-2019